# Supercapacitor discharging

Tags: voltage, capacitor, supercapacitor, capacitor-charging

I had bought a Maxwell ultracapacitor ([this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/151633361695)) rated for 1200F at 2.7V. Its ESR according to the datasheet should in ballpark of 0.4 milliohms.
It got delivered today and is undamaged and new by appearence. However, I don't understand something.
To test it, I charged the capacitor briefly (with a 1.8V supply with 1A peak current) to 50mV and shorted it across a wire (it charged very slowly as expected from a supercapacitor). Nothing.
I tried again with 500mV. Still nothing.
Then with 750mV. Still doesn't do anything.
To, investigate it further, I charged it to 750mV and shorted it across a wire with the multimeter in parallel set in voltimeter mode. When I shorted it for 2 seconds,the voltage dropped close to zero when the short was active. However, upon removing the short, the voltage climbed immediately back to 750mV.
This is behaving as if the ESR of the cap is really high and doesn't even discharge easily with a dead short.
Why is it doing this and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: 400 uOhms is implausibly low.  Link to a real datasheet.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: those have indeed ~500-600 µOhms ESR but of course measured in the best possible way and circumstances, which are far from the situation described here. http://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/K2Series_DS_1015370_5_20141104.pdf If you are intrested in the "datasheet"

Comment: @OlinLathrop - The capacitor alone is the size of a soda can. You can arc weld with these things. ESR values in the uOhms is very reasonable.

Comment: What are you shorting it with? Can you measure the current when shorting it? Perhaps short via a low resistor and see what voltage is across that

Comment: @Jodes Shorting it with plain 20AWG  3cm copper wire. The voltage drops to nearly 10-20mV

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing your set-up. Did you just touch the wire on the poles, or did you give it a good connection? And was the multimeter touching the capacitor's poles, or was it attached to the wire? I suggest trying to deduce the ESR and capacitance by whatever means; either the unit is faulty and you should return it, or there is just a bad connection somewhere.

Comment: That is, unless you're seeing sparks and that wire is getting extremely hot, in which case it is probably working as expected.

Comment: @Jodes the wire get hot to touch. It doesn't melt or give off sparks like expected.